# mvc4 bundling and minification - use standard minified jquery libs

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, cdn, bundling-and-minification

I understand the principle behind the bundling and minification with mvc4, but I would like to use the basic pre-minified libraries for such items as jquery and other large and common libs.

Thus, in my production version, instead of referencing a bundle like this:

```
bundles/jquerymobile?v=N1H63GRw6_-3057BORWSW60RX5rLWde08XZf8PiKQaE1
```

I would prefer to use the standard jquery min version, like this:

```
jquery-1.8.2.min.js
```

Then my next step will be to allow replacing these standardized libs with CDN hosted ones, such as the ones that google and other big cdn's make available.

So: two parts to this question:

-How can I instruct the bundler to directly include a pre-minified file, unbundled with others?

-How can I create a link to a CDN hosted version of this file instead of referencing local ones?

Comment: Can't you include `jquery-1.8.2.min.js` directly without the bundler?

Comment: I have the non-minified version automatically referenced in debug mode. When I switch to release mode, I'd like the min versions referenced instead.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would prefer to use the standard jquery min version, like this: jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Why? If you bundle it with the rest of your scripts it's still minified, and it's one less HTTP request. There is no functional difference if you bundle this script with the others. Bundling it simply reduces HTTP requests (which is probably more important than minifying).

#### How can I instruct the bundler to directly include a pre-minified file, unbundled with others?

You don't, you include the script on the page like normal. If you want to use the bundler for the sole purposes of minifying your script, then create a separate bundle with just that one script.

#### How can I create a link to a CDN hosted version of this file instead of referencing local ones?

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

Comment: If you use a common cdn hosted lib, there is a good chance it is already cached on the client's machine, thus completely eliminating that request. This is especially useful for the larger files like jquery. If a user has visited google (and who hasn't), they likely already have it.

Comment: sorry, my comment was addressed to the cdn issue.

Comment: This is completely true, however what about the cases where they had their data wiped. They will have to download 2+ scripts instead of one. One bigger script is totally better than 2+ scripts. I've done a lot of reading on web performance, including an article from yahoo, and it seems the general consensus is that larger file size is always favored over more HTTP requests. I think you'll be fine either way you go, but it might be fun to test download time for one script containing all the scripts versus breaking out the jquery stuff.